# ViewModel: Unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I want to implement `ViewModel` into my app, but I cant import `viewModels()` or `activityViewModels()`. Trying to follow tutorial but its still unresolved reference for me.

```
private val userViewModel: ProfileFlowFragment.UserViewModel by viewModels()
```

Imports:

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx"

// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0"
// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you specify the version in `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx"` ?
Anyway, I have these dependencies in my Gradle file, and everything is fine.

```
 implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$corektxVersion"
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_stdlibVersion"
```

Also add

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' was missing. Now it works

Comment: I'm a noob and I need context.  Context?  Where should one place these statements?

Answer (score 1):

The latest stable versions are below, it should work.

```
 def activity_version = "1.2.0"
 def fragment_version = "1.3.0"
 implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version"
 implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
```