# by viewModels() Unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, viewmodel

I have a problem, Android Studio highlights `by viewModels()` as an error, but the code is successfully compiled and works. This problem occurs only in Activity, in Fragment there is no such error. The same will happen if I use `by viewModel()` (Koin) instead of `by viewModels()`. I’ve looked at a lot of decisions, but none of them helped me.

I tried:

- Invalidate Caches
- Restart IDE, PC...
- Open a project on another PC
- Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63804803/unresolved-reference-viewmodels-hilt) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66526202/viewmodel-unresolved-reference)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI8Mm.png)

My dependencies (app):

```
implementation(project(":domain"))
implementation(project(":data"))

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'

def koin_version= "3.2.1"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.3"
implementation 'com.my.target:mytarget-sdk:5.15.4'

def lottieVersion = "5.2.0"
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.2.13'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.2'
```

Build gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:oss-licenses-plugin:0.10.5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue also. AppCompatActivity is deriving from ComposeActivity but somehow Android Studio isn't getting this and showing it as an error.